# passing C++ string to Python

Tags: c++, python

How could I pass a string from C++ to my Python function? I would like to get the string in my C++ application and parse it in Python

Comment: Check out [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/)

Comment: Or read the docs in the C API section.

Comment: Some clarification on what I'm trying to do: I have a float var in C++ that I would like to pass to a Python function that takes a float as a parameter. However, print statements in Python for the variable are outputting gibberish--I suspect that floats have different bits of precision? In C++ there are 7 bits after the decimal point, in Python, 6. So I want to convert the float to a string in C++, pass that to Python, truncate the number after the 6th decimal point, and convert it back to a float.

Comment: The precision bits is a non-issue here. Python uses the same internal representation as C, because the interpreter is written in C. Anyway, PyFloat_FromDouble() should work. If not, you are doing something wrong, and the question should be about that, preferably with some code.

Comment: If you *just* want to pass a float between Python and C++, the quickest way to do it is to pass it via a file, especially if performance doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @jyoung: Are you embedding or extending Python, or do you just have separate C++ and Python programs?

Answer (score 2):

Initialize all required variables first.

```
Py_Initialize();
object  main_module = import("__main__");//boost::python objects
object  dictionary = main_module.attr("__dict__");
```

Run a code to create a variable and set an initial value and print it inside python.

```
boost::python::exec("resultStr = 'oldvalue'", dictionary);
PyRun_SimpleString("print resultStr");//new value will reflect in python
```

read the same variable from c++.

```
boost::python::object resultStr = dictionary["resultStr"];//read value from python to c++
std::string &processedScript = extract<std::string>(resultStr);
```

Above dictionary object is like a shared map. you can set a variable from c++.
Then check the new value from python.

```
dictionary["resultStr"] = "new value";//set the variable value
PyRun_SimpleString("print resultStr");//new value will reflect in python
```

Have fun coding.
Thanks.